# UserTransaction.getStatus() always returns '6'

Tags: jakarta-ee, transactions, websphere

UserTransaction.getStatus() method is always returning the value '6', even immediately after performing rollback or commit. Cannot understand why the status is not changing. Can someone point out whats wrong here?
I am using WAS 6.1.

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
UserTransaction utx = (UserTransaction)context.lookup("java:comp/UserTransaction");
System.out.println("Transaction status = "+utx.getStatus());  //value is 6

utx.begin()
//all work done here

if(all good) {utx.commit()}
else {
utx.rollback();
System.out.println("Transaction status = "+utx.getStatus());  //value is 6
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value 6 means `STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION`. It is normal that you get this result before the start of the transaction and after the commit or rollback.

Answer (score 11):

Andreas already has the answer. I'd just like to add some detail for people like me, who may think STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION is not an intuitive state for a completed transaction, since we also have a STATUS_COMMITTED in the list.

Here are all the states that a transaction can possess [as listed in EE6 javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html);

```
STATUS_ACTIVE               0
STATUS_COMMITTED            3
STATUS_COMMITTING           8
STATUS_MARKED_ROLLBACK      1
STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION       6
STATUS_PREPARED             2
STATUS_PREPARING            7
STATUS_ROLLEDBACK           4
STATUS_ROLLING_BACK         9
STATUS_UNKNOWN              5
```

On the javadocs, it clearly states that we'll get an STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION after the transaction completes (commit or rollback)

```
static final int STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION
    No transaction is currently associated with the target object. 
    This will occur after a transaction has completed.
```

So when do we have STATUS_ROLLEDBACK and STATUS_COMMITTED? Javadocs, similar for these two states, reveal that these corresponds to somehow problematic states, if there were no problems you'd get a STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION instead;

```
static final int STATUS_COMMITTED
    A transaction is associated with the target object and it has been committed. 
    It is likely that heuristics exist; otherwise, the transaction 
    would have been destroyed and NoTransaction returned.
```

Heuristics?

Here is the definition;

> A heuristic completion (or heuristic decision) occurs when a resource
>   makes a unilateral decision during the completion stage of a
>   distributed transaction to commit or rollback updates. This can leave
>   distributed data in an indeterminate state. Network failures or
>   resource timeouts are possible causes for heuristic completion.

That means, simply stated, something went wrong with your XA transaction, possibly due to a transient condition like network, timeouts etc.

Fair enough.

Also, it may worth noting that, how WebSphere deals with these heuristic completions can be configured via heuristic-related properties outlined at [Configuring transaction properties for an application server](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tjta_settlog.html)

Comment: I wasn't able to see the status explanations in the javadoc link provided in this answer. In case somebody else is looking for them, you can see them in [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Status.html#STATUS_ACTIVE) and numeric values [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/constant-values.html#javax.transaction.Status.STATUS_ACTIVE). Thank you for an excellent answer!

Comment: So, rephrasing in even less words: you will get STATUS_NO_TRANSACTION every time the transaction has been successfully completed. Am I understanding this correctly? This is contrary to what the logic would suggest - eg. I was expecting to receive a STATUS_ROLLEDBACK if the transaction was rolled back.